# R multi-hot encoding among multiple columns

Tags: r, one-hot-encoding, dummy-variable

My data is in the shape

```
Event Id Var1 Var2 Var3
1      a   x    w    y
2      a   z    y    w
3      b   x    y    q
```

and I need to create multi-hot encoded vectors for each row in the table, considering all the values appearing in Var1, Var2 and Var3.
Meaning that the desired output would be:

```
Event Id  x  y  z  w  q
1      a  1  1  0  1  0
2      a  0  1  1  1  0
3      b  1  1  0  0  1
```

Meaning that I keep the same number of rows of the initial dataset, I only add for each row a number of columns equal to all the unique factors among Var 1, Var 2 and Var3.

I tried all aproaches I could think of, but nothing seems to work so far..

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data.table` -

```
dt <- read.table(text="Event Id Var1 Var2 Var3
1      a   x    w    y
2      a   z    y    w
3      b   x    y    q",header=T)

setDT(dt)
dcast(setDT(melt(dt,id.vars = c("Event","Id")))[,ind:=1],Event+Id~value,value.var = "ind",fill=0)
```

Output-

```
   Event Id Var1 Var2 Var3 q w x y z
1:     1  a    1    1    1 0 1 1 1 0
2:     2  a    1    1    1 0 1 0 1 1
3:     3  b    1    1    1 1 0 1 1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

We could `gather` into 'long' format and then do a `spread`

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df1, key, val, Var1:Var3) %>%
   mutate(n = 1) %>%
   select(-key) %>% 
   spread(val, n, fill = 0)
```

---

Or in a compact way

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(df1[1:2], +(mtabulate(df1[-(1:2)]) > 0))
```